# Настройка Sphinx

Tags: php, yii2, sphinx, sphinxsearch

Хочу начать использовать Sphinx, так как есть сайт с большой базой и медленными запросами. Всякая оптимизация не помогла достичь нужной скорости, поэтому решил попробовать Sphinx.

У меня такой вопрос: если я возьму весь медленный запрос (там штук 5 или 6 join) и просто его добавлю в Sphinx - это будет правильно?

Извините, если вопрос не уместный, просто не нашел нормально документации по поводу именно построения запросов.

Comment: Sphinx не поддерживает JOIN. Вполне возможно, что всё можно ускорить и без JOIN с помощью грамотно проставленных индексов, но без точного описания задачи ответить что-то конкретное невозможно

Comment: речь идет о базе tecdoc. сколько не пробовал ускорить добавлением индексов - не помогло

Comment: Напишите свой тяжелый запрос и используйте его в конфиге свинкса как источник данных - поле `sql_query`. Мускул построит таблицу по вашему тяжелому запросу, Сфинкс проиндексирует. Будет летать. Если данные часто меняются, используй rt-индексы.

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx принимает SQL запросы так как работает на базе драйвера mysql но со своим расширенным синтаксисом, например MATHC или FACETS и.т.д.

Просто запрос перенести можно (если конечно там не OR или каких-либо специфичных для БД литератлов. Но болле правильным будет провести анализ запроса и понять что в нем замедляет выполнение и решить как можно его перестроить или упростить с использованием Sphinx. Для примера можно подумать в сторону реструктуризации хранимых данных, денормализации, шардировании и.т.д.

Еще нужно держать во внимании что Sphinx является в первую очередь движком полнотекстового поиска а уже потом базой данных.

Если требуется множество агрегаций по полям то можно подумать в сторону колоночных БД (click house и подобные).

Answer (score 0):

Судя по вашему комментарию у вас база от tecdoc. На самом деле у этой базы отвратительная оптимизация, хотя разработчики верят, что всё у них идеально.

Зачастую эту базу используют по другому,  а именно как интеграция к движку. Недавно ко мне попал в руки сайт на OpenCart, где была база текдок. Там была реализована синхронизация базы OpenCart и базы текдок по крону. А некоторые данные, которым не удалось сделать синхронизацию, вытаскивались через простенькие запросы. Но даже простые запросы слишком долго выполнялись, в этом случаи помог переезд на хороший выделенный сервер.